# Recently washed road bike now squeaks when pedaling or coasting

Tags: road-bike, noise

I just did a wash in what I felt was the proper way (I've watched the tutorials lol) of my Cannondale CAAD12 roadie. I lubed it up like I normally do with some dry teflon lube on the chain and some spray teflon lube in the important bits... go out riding today and it's squeaky as hell, fairly high pitched. Happens when pedalling and when I coast (for a bit after letting off the gas). Where should I start to look? Did I mess my BB?

Thanks guys in advance you usually help me out quite a bit!

Comment: I'd suspect you didn't lubricate something sufficiently - spray lube isn't really that good at getting into things.

Comment: Have you checked out the Sheldon Brown page on identifying noises? https://www.sheldonbrown.com/creaks.html

Comment: Washed how?  Bearings subjected to water sprays with any pressure behind the spray tend to lose just about all their lubrication. Going as far as powerwashing a bicycle is just about the worst thing you can do to the bearings.

Answer (score 1):

When does it squeak?

If it squeaks even while you are coasting it can’t be the bottom bracket, chain, pedals or rear derailleur. If it *only* squeaks while you are coasting it could be the free wheel.

If it squeaks all the time it could be the brakes (should be more of a rubbing sound) or hub bearings (though those usually don’t “squeak”).